# Problem to convert a String into a Table with pattern matching

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

Given is the string:

```
local a = "#5*$4a+02/+2-%110"
```

Now i want to split the following string into a table like

```
b[1]="5" 
b[2]="*" 
b[3]="$4a" 
b[4]="+" 
... 
b[10]="%110"
```

My solution was

```
local b = {}

for part in string.gmatch(a,"[%x%$%%]+[%+%-%/%*]+") do 
    b[#b+1] = part 
end
```

But i get

```
   b[1]="5*"
   b[2]="$4a+"
   b[3]="02/"
   ...
```

but without the last number: %110.

Comment: How about adding `%d` or `%x` to your second character class? I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve here though.

Comment: You want `string.match`, not `string.gmatch`

Comment: @Don't write comments as answers.

Comment: @Zakk Thank you, but i've seen my fault ... But now, what have you to say about my Question?

Answer (score 0):

You mean:

```
string.gmatch(a,"[%x%$%%]+[%+%-%/%*]+[%x%$%%]")
```

This result was an empty Table.
I want to caclulate the formula in that string.

```
local a = "#5*$4a+02/+2-%110"
```

The problem is now, a eval like

```
function evalStr(str)
   local f= load ('return ('..str..')')
   return f()
end
```

can calculate this Formula only with Decimal-Digits. Here i it is mixed with Hexadecimal and Binary Digits.
So i have to to convert the hexadecimal and binary digits to decimal to calculate the formula.

Answer (score 0):

```
local a = "#5*$4a+02/+2-%110"
local b = {}

for part in string.gmatch(a,"[^#][%x%%%$]*[%+%-%*/]*") do
    b[#b+1] = part:match("[%w%%%$]+")
    b[#b+1] = part:match("[%+%-%*/]")
    
end

for k,v in pairs(b) do
    print(v)

end
```

Comment: This is the solution for my problem. Thanks all for your help.